# Sync Internet Accounts between OS X and iOS via iCloud

Tags: icloud, accounts

I have setup iCloud and Keychain on both OS X and iOS, but my Internet Accounts do not seem to be synced (iOS Mail doesn't show all my inboxes).

Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks.